# How can I add another column comparison to an existing comparison?

Tags: google-apps-script

How can I add comparison with the value in column A such that:

if value on column A is test1 I'll send an email to test1@mail.com,
if value is test2 ill send email to tes2@mail.com and etc.

```
function sendEmailAlert() {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var data = ss.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
    var sheetname = ss.getActiveSheet().getName();
    var getColumn = ss.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange().getColumn();
    var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
    var Toemail = 'randomemail@mail.com';
    var subject = 'New Entry -' + ss.getName();
    var body = 'random text';

    if(Number(ss.getActiveCell().getValue()!=-1.23456789) && getColumn ==2) {

         MailApp.sendEmail(Toemail,subject,body); 
    }
};

If I change value in column B, and the value in column A is `test1` I'll send email to test1@mail.com.  If I change column B and value in column A is `test2` I'll send email to test2mail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `getCell(row, column)` function available on a `Range` object to get the contents of the cell to the left of the currently active cell (assuming the first column is the email address, and the second column contains the cells being modified). The following code snippet chooses the destination email address of an email as such, sending as the body the value of the cell that was changed:

```js
function sendEmail() {

  // Spreadsheet info
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // get all sheets
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(); // get current sheet
  var data = sheet.getDataRange(); // get all data in the active sheet
  var sheetname = sheet.getName();

  // Current cell info
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var currColumn = cell.getColumn();
  var currRow = cell.getRow();

  // Email setup
  var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var subject = 'New Entry - ' + ss.getName();

  // Do I send an email?
  if(Number(ss.getActiveCell().getValue() != -1.23456789) && currColumn == 2) {
    var toEmail = String(data.getCell(currRow, currColumn - 1).getValue());
    var body = data.getCell(currRow, currColumn).getValue();
    MailApp.sendEmail(toEmail, subject, body);
  }

};
```

The important line is the one defining the `toEmail`, which asks for `currColumn - 1`.